# How does the class activate on a menu with bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu, navigation

I have a site with "Drupal 8" and "Bootstrap 3.3.7".

In the Drupal menu, when the "Article" page is displayed, link to this page in the menu at the "active" class on "li". Here's what the code looks like :

```
<nav role="navigation" aria-labelledby="block-navigationprincipale-menu" id="block-navigationprincipale" class="contextual-region">
      <h2 id="block-navigationprincipale-menu">Navigation principale</h2>


      <ul class="menu menu--main nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>
        <a href="/profil" data-drupal-link-system-path="profil">Profils</a>
                  </li>
                        <li>
        <a href="/boutique" data-drupal-link-system-path="boutique">Boutiques</a>
                  </li>
                        <li>
        <a href="/produit" data-drupal-link-system-path="produit">Produits</a>
                  </li>
                        <li>
        <a href="/service" data-drupal-link-system-path="service">Services</a>
                  </li>
                        <li>
        <a href="/groupe" data-drupal-link-system-path="groupe">Groupes</a>
                  </li>
                        <li>
        <a href="/annonce" data-drupal-link-system-path="annonce">Annonce</a>
                  </li>
                        <li class="active">
        <a href="/article" data-drupal-link-system-path="article" class="is-active">Articles</a>
                  </li>
                        <li>
        <a href="/discussion" data-drupal-link-system-path="discussion">Discussions</a>
                  </li>
                        <li>
        <a href="/recette" data-drupal-link-system-path="recette">Recettes</a>
                  </li>
                        <li>
        <a href="/itineraire" data-drupal-link-system-path="itineraire">Itinéraires</a>
                  </li>
                        <li>
        <a href="/evenement" data-drupal-link-system-path="evenement">Événements</a>
                  </li>
        </ul>


  </nav>
```

MY PROBLEM :

I created a custom menu block and the "active" class is not added to "li". Here is my code :

```
<nav role="navigation" aria-labelledby="block-navigationprincipale-menu" id="block-navigationprincipale" class="contextual-region">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown open">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true"><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-minus-circle fa-w-16 fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="minus-circle" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M256 8C119 8 8 119 8 256s111 248 248 248 248-111 248-248S393 8 256 8zM124 296c-6.6 0-12-5.4-12-12v-56c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12h264c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v56c0 6.6-5.4 12-12 12H124z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i> --> Menu principal</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="/profil" data-drupal-link-system-path="profil"><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-id-card fa-w-16 fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="id-card" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M464 64H48C21.49 64 0 85.49 0 112v288c0 26.51 21.49 48 48 48h416c26.51 0 48-21.49 48-48V112c0-26.51-21.49-48-48-48zM256 350c0 9.941-8.059 18-18 18H82c-9.941 0-18-8.059-18-18v-13.892c0-16.519 11.243-30.919 27.269-34.925l26.742-6.686c21.826 15.699 55.882 20.209 83.978 0l26.743 6.686C244.757 305.189 256 319.589 256 336.108V350zM100 236c0-33.137 26.863-60 60-60s60 26.863 60 60-26.863 60-60 60-60-26.863-60-60zm348 104c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12H300c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-8c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h136c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v8zm0-64c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12H300c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-8c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h136c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v8zm0-64c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12H300c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-8c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h136c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v8zm32-96c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12H44c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-8c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h424c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v8z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fas fa-id-card fa-lg"></i> --> Profils</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/boutique" data-drupal-link-system-path="boutique"><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-shopping-bag fa-w-14 fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="shopping-bag" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M352 160v-32C352 57.42 294.579 0 224 0 153.42 0 96 57.42 96 128v32H0v272c0 44.183 35.817 80 80 80h288c44.183 0 80-35.817 80-80V160h-96zm-192-32c0-35.29 28.71-64 64-64s64 28.71 64 64v32H160v-32zm160 120c-13.255 0-24-10.745-24-24s10.745-24 24-24 24 10.745 24 24-10.745 24-24 24zm-192 0c-13.255 0-24-10.745-24-24s10.745-24 24-24 24 10.745 24 24-10.745 24-24 24z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fas fa-shopping-bag fa-lg"></i> --> Boutiques</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/produit" data-drupal-link-system-path="produit"><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-gift fa-w-16 fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="gift" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M32 448c0 17.7 14.3 32 32 32h160V320H32v128zm448-288h-42.1c6.2-12.1 10.1-25.5 10.1-40 0-48.5-39.5-88-88-88-41.6 0-68.5 21.3-103 68.3-34.5-47-61.4-68.3-103-68.3-48.5 0-88 39.5-88 88 0 14.5 3.8 27.9 10.1 40H32c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32v80c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16h480c8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16v-80c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32zm-326.1 0c-22.1 0-40-17.9-40-40s17.9-40 40-40c19.9 0 34.6 3.3 86.1 80h-86.1zm206.1 0h-86.1c51.4-76.5 65.7-80 86.1-80 22.1 0 40 17.9 40 40s-17.9 40-40 40zm-72 320h160c17.7 0 32-14.3 32-32V320H288v160z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fas fa-gift fa-lg"></i> --> Produits</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/service" data-drupal-link-system-path="service"><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-sign-language fa-w-14 fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="sign-language" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M91.434 483.987c-.307-16.018 13.109-29.129 29.13-29.129h62.293v-5.714H56.993c-16.021 0-29.437-13.111-29.13-29.129C28.16 404.491 40.835 392 56.428 392h126.429v-5.714H29.136c-16.021 0-29.437-13.111-29.13-29.129.297-15.522 12.973-28.013 28.566-28.013h154.286v-5.714H57.707c-16.021 0-29.437-13.111-29.13-29.129.297-15.522 12.973-28.013 28.566-28.013h168.566l-31.085-22.606c-12.762-9.281-15.583-27.149-6.302-39.912 9.281-12.761 27.15-15.582 39.912-6.302l123.361 89.715a34.287 34.287 0 0 1 14.12 27.728v141.136c0 15.91-10.946 29.73-26.433 33.374l-80.471 18.934a137.16 137.16 0 0 1-31.411 3.646H120c-15.593-.001-28.269-12.492-28.566-28.014zm73.249-225.701h36.423l-11.187-8.136c-18.579-13.511-20.313-40.887-3.17-56.536l-13.004-16.7c-9.843-12.641-28.43-15.171-40.88-5.088-12.065 9.771-14.133 27.447-4.553 39.75l36.371 46.71zm283.298-2.103l-5.003-152.452c-.518-15.771-13.722-28.136-29.493-27.619-15.773.518-28.137 13.722-27.619 29.493l1.262 38.415L283.565 11.019c-9.58-12.303-27.223-14.63-39.653-5.328-12.827 9.599-14.929 28.24-5.086 40.881l76.889 98.745-4.509 3.511-94.79-121.734c-9.58-12.303-27.223-14.63-39.653-5.328-12.827 9.599-14.929 28.24-5.086 40.881l94.443 121.288-4.509 3.511-77.675-99.754c-9.58-12.303-27.223-14.63-39.653-5.328-12.827 9.599-14.929 28.24-5.086 40.881l52.053 66.849c12.497-8.257 29.055-8.285 41.69.904l123.36 89.714c10.904 7.93 17.415 20.715 17.415 34.198v16.999l61.064-47.549a34.285 34.285 0 0 0 13.202-28.177z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fas fa-sign-language fa-lg"></i> --> Services</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/groupe" data-drupal-link-system-path="groupe"><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-users fa-w-20 fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="users" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 640 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M320 64c57.99 0 105 47.01 105 105s-47.01 105-105 105-105-47.01-105-105S262.01 64 320 64zm113.463 217.366l-39.982-9.996c-49.168 35.365-108.766 27.473-146.961 0l-39.982 9.996C174.485 289.379 152 318.177 152 351.216V412c0 19.882 16.118 36 36 36h264c19.882 0 36-16.118 36-36v-60.784c0-33.039-22.485-61.837-54.537-69.85zM528 300c38.66 0 70-31.34 70-70s-31.34-70-70-70-70 31.34-70 70 31.34 70 70 70zm-416 0c38.66 0 70-31.34 70-70s-31.34-70-70-70-70 31.34-70 70 31.34 70 70 70zm24 112v-60.784c0-16.551 4.593-32.204 12.703-45.599-29.988 14.72-63.336 8.708-85.69-7.37l-26.655 6.664C14.99 310.252 0 329.452 0 351.477V392c0 13.255 10.745 24 24 24h112.169a52.417 52.417 0 0 1-.169-4zm467.642-107.09l-26.655-6.664c-27.925 20.086-60.89 19.233-85.786 7.218C499.369 318.893 504 334.601 504 351.216V412c0 1.347-.068 2.678-.169 4H616c13.255 0 24-10.745 24-24v-40.523c0-22.025-14.99-41.225-36.358-46.567z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fas fa-users fa-lg"></i> --> Groupes</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/annonce" data-drupal-link-system-path="annonce"><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-newspaper fa-w-18 fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="newspaper" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M552 64H88c-13.255 0-24 10.745-24 24v8H24c-13.255 0-24 10.745-24 24v272c0 30.928 25.072 56 56 56h472c26.51 0 48-21.49 48-48V88c0-13.255-10.745-24-24-24zM56 400a8 8 0 0 1-8-8V144h16v248a8 8 0 0 1-8 8zm236-16H140c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-8c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h152c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v8c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12zm208 0H348c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-8c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h152c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v8c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12zm-208-96H140c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-8c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h152c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v8c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12zm208 0H348c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-8c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h152c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v8c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12zm0-96H140c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-40c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h360c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v40c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fas fa-newspaper fa-lg"></i> --> Annonces</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/article" data-drupal-link-system-path="article" class="is-active"><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-file-alt fa-w-12 fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="file-alt" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 384 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M224 136V0H24C10.7 0 0 10.7 0 24v464c0 13.3 10.7 24 24 24h336c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24V160H248c-13.2 0-24-10.8-24-24zm64 236c0 6.6-5.4 12-12 12H108c-6.6 0-12-5.4-12-12v-8c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12h168c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v8zm0-64c0 6.6-5.4 12-12 12H108c-6.6 0-12-5.4-12-12v-8c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12h168c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v8zm0-72v8c0 6.6-5.4 12-12 12H108c-6.6 0-12-5.4-12-12v-8c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12h168c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12zm96-114.1v6.1H256V0h6.1c6.4 0 12.5 2.5 17 7l97.9 98c4.5 4.5 7 10.6 7 16.9z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fas fa-file-alt fa-lg"></i> --> Articles</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/discussion" data-drupal-link-system-path="discussion"><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-comments fa-w-18 fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="comments" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M416 192c0-88.4-93.1-160-208-160S0 103.6 0 192c0 34.3 14.1 65.9 38 92-13.4 30.2-35.5 54.2-35.8 54.5-2.2 2.3-2.8 5.7-1.5 8.7S4.8 352 8 352c36.6 0 66.9-12.3 88.7-25 32.2 15.7 70.3 25 111.3 25 114.9 0 208-71.6 208-160zm122 220c23.9-26 38-57.7 38-92 0-66.9-53.5-124.2-129.3-148.1.9 6.6 1.3 13.3 1.3 20.1 0 105.9-107.7 192-240 192-10.8 0-21.3-.8-31.7-1.9C207.8 439.6 281.8 480 368 480c41 0 79.1-9.2 111.3-25 21.8 12.7 52.1 25 88.7 25 3.2 0 6.1-1.9 7.3-4.8 1.3-2.9.7-6.3-1.5-8.7-.3-.3-22.4-24.2-35.8-54.5z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fas fa-comments fa-lg"></i> --> Discussions</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/recette" data-drupal-link-system-path="recette"><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-utensils fa-w-13 fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="utensils" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 416 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M207.9 15.2c.8 4.7 16.1 94.5 16.1 128.8 0 52.3-27.8 89.6-68.9 104.6L168 486.7c.7 13.7-10.2 25.3-24 25.3H80c-13.7 0-24.7-11.5-24-25.3l12.9-238.1C27.7 233.6 0 196.2 0 144 0 109.6 15.3 19.9 16.1 15.2 19.3-5.1 61.4-5.4 64 16.3v141.2c1.3 3.4 15.1 3.2 16 0 1.4-25.3 7.9-139.2 8-141.8 3.3-20.8 44.7-20.8 47.9 0 .2 2.7 6.6 116.5 8 141.8.9 3.2 14.8 3.4 16 0V16.3c2.6-21.6 44.8-21.4 48-1.1zm119.2 285.7l-15 185.1c-1.2 14 9.9 26 23.9 26h56c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24V24c0-13.2-10.7-24-24-24-82.5 0-221.4 178.5-64.9 300.9z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fas fa-utensils fa-lg"></i> --> Recettes</a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="/itineraire" data-drupal-link-system-path="itineraire"><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-map-signs fa-w-16 fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="map-signs" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M487.515 104.485L439.03 152.97a23.998 23.998 0 0 1-16.97 7.029H56c-13.255 0-24-10.745-24-24V56c0-13.255 10.745-24 24-24h160v-8c0-13.255 10.745-24 24-24h32c13.255 0 24 10.745 24 24v8h126.059a24 24 0 0 1 16.97 7.029l48.485 48.485c4.687 4.687 4.687 12.285.001 16.971zM216 368v120c0 13.255 10.745 24 24 24h32c13.255 0 24-10.745 24-24V368h-80zm240-144H296v-48h-80v48H89.941a24 24 0 0 0-16.97 7.029l-48.485 48.485c-4.686 4.686-4.686 12.284 0 16.971l48.485 48.485a23.998 23.998 0 0 0 16.97 7.029H456c13.255 0 24-10.745 24-24v-80C480 234.745 469.255 224 456 224z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fas fa-map-signs fa-lg"></i> --> Itinéraires</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/evenement" data-drupal-link-system-path="evenement"><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-calendar fa-w-14 fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="calendar" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M12 192h424c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v260c0 26.5-21.5 48-48 48H48c-26.5 0-48-21.5-48-48V204c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12zm436-44v-36c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48h-48V12c0-6.6-5.4-12-12-12h-40c-6.6 0-12 5.4-12 12v52H160V12c0-6.6-5.4-12-12-12h-40c-6.6 0-12 5.4-12 12v52H48C21.5 64 0 85.5 0 112v36c0 6.6 5.4 12 12 12h424c6.6 0 12-5.4 12-12z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fas fa-calendar fa-lg"></i> --> Événements</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Why is the "active" class not added to "li" ?

I noticed that the class "is-active" is added to "a"

Comment: Is ur ul inside a nav tag?

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO I do not understand what you mean by nav tag

Comment: ``<nav>`` tag. HTML tags?

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO I updated my question and I encountered the same problem

Comment: Can you set a live view of your code so i can debbug it

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO It's on this page https://www.s1biose.com/annonce in the menu at the top left and "Menu principal".

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO Where did you find the problem ? thank you